# Are there any issues with allocating memory within constructor initialization lists?

Tags: c++

I have used initialization lists a great deal in my C++ programs but wasn't aware that you could allocate memory within them.

So you can do something (as a contrived example) like this:

```
class Test
{
private:
    int* i;
    int* j;
    int count;
    int* k;

public:
    Test(void) : i(new int), j(new int[10]), count(10), k(new int[count])
    {
    }

    ~Test(void)
    {
        delete i;
        delete [] j;
        delete [] k;
    }
};
```

Are there any issues in doing memory allocation in this way? Regarding the order of initialization here is it safe to have a parameter initialized by one initialized in the same list? i.e. as I allocate `count` before I use it is it safe to use or is there some special initialization order I could fall foul of?

Comment: Note that the order of intialization is not determined by the ctor initializer but the declaration order of the variables. Also note that a proper answer possibly depends on whether you want your code to be exception safe in the presence of new throwing or not.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's not exception-safe. If the `new` for `j` throws an exception then the destructor for `Test` is not called, and so the memory for `i` is not freed.

The destructor of `i` is called if the initializer for `j` throws, it's just that a raw pointer has no destructor. So you could make it exception-safe by replacing `i` with a suitable smart pointer. In this case, `unique_ptr<int>` for `i` and `unique_ptr<int[]>` for `j` would do.

You can rely on the initializers to be executed in their correct order (the order the members are defined, not necessarily the order in the list). They can safely use data members that have already been initialized, so there's no problem with using `count` in the initializer for `k`.

Comment: So specifically, this is a problem if the class calls `new` more than once in the initializer list. :)

Comment: I am aware that you can add exception handlers into the initialization list, if you did that would that solve that issue or make others?

Comment: That's not much of a problem -- most people do several `new`'s in a constructor, and don't care for wrapping them up in a try block -- in the usual case (not server-software etc) the run-out-of-memory-case is OMG-we're scutling the boat-type of situation.

Comment: @Firedragon - no, because you'd have no way to guarantee that your member variables are nil at time of creation, so you coulnd't judge which ones were already initialized.

Comment: @jalf: You don't need to use `new` more than once; any subsequently constructed members can fail.  If you want to be snarky, you could say that it's not a problem if you use `new` only once if it's the last member...

Comment: @Firedragon: The easiest way to make it exception safe is to use smart pointers rather than raw pointers; this will also mean you don't need to write a destructor, or the copy constructor and copy-assignment operator that are missing from your class. Adding exception handlers is rather ugly, and a bit fiddly to get right.

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz the problem is not only with out if memory, but any exception thrown in a later constructor call, which makes this an issue not only in the server side, but in all contexts

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks for that Mike. It is a very contrived example but I was curious about what is possible as I am realising that in C++ you can work in it for many years and still have a lot to learn :-) It's interesting what you can do, regardless how safe (or not) it is

Comment: You could use the nothrow version of new.

Comment: @avid: you could, but that weakens the class invariants to something much less useful. Instead of "this class has three dynamically-allocated things", it's "this class has between 0 and 3 dynamically-allocated things".

Comment: @SteveJessop Maybe.  You still have the body of the constructor to enforce the class invariants, cleaning up and throwing if they aren't met.

Comment: @SteveJessop That is true, I was thinking about what would happen and basically you would still either have to check for nulls on first use everywhere or just perform the check in the constructor and throw a no memory exception anyway.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Smart pointers are one solution.  Another that I've seen used is to push all of the pointers down into a private base class, whose constructor initializes them to `NULL`, and whose destructor deletes them (but the `new`s are in the constructor body of the derived class).

Comment: Yeah true, my point was to emphasize that *just* calling `new` is safe enough in itself. The problem is when you do that and also perform other operations that may throw

Comment: @James: good point, I hadn't thought of that. I think that if I was going to test the result of `new` in the constructor body, though, then I'd probably prefer to initialize the pointers to `0` and then call `new` in the constructor body, rather than putting a load of nothrow new calls in the initializers.

Comment: @SteveJessop Me too, probably.  At least, the cases I know where people have used this approach were generally because it was impossible to do the allocations in the initialization list, or because some of the constructors actually left the pointers null (e.g. `std::vector` in the g++ library).  (If you're using the pimpl idiom, the pimpl can play the same role as the base class here; if anything goes wrong during construction, you delete the pimpl.)

Comment: i was expecting same just what you said. However, this example just shows constructor being called for the first while destructor isnt called. Any reason related to compiler?Example: http://ideone.com/DZJaVN

Comment: @Abhinav: There's nothing implementation-specific about your code other than whether or not it has enough memory for the allocation to succeed. `Wrapper::one` is a pointer. When the initializer for `Wrapper::two` throws, it's just like the questioner's case, nothing happens to whatever `one` points at.

Answer (score 6):

This code could leak memory in the presence of an initializer that throws an exception.

Note that this could be made to work correctly if the members of `Test` were smart -- rather than raw -- pointers.

Answer (score 3):

There's no problem with your initialization -- they are guaranteed by the standard to be done in order, however, do remember that if any of those allocations fails, the former ones won't be freed.

So the only downside is if you want to keep safe against a failed allocation -- then you'd rather want to initialize them to `nil` and in the constructor wrap the allocation up in a `try` block. That  is usually not needed though, unless your application is in the real danger of running out of memory, and needs to recover from that.

Of course that holds true assuming that only a lack of memory can throw an exception -- if you allocate objects that can throw other exceptions, you should be more worried about it.

Comment: "That is usually not needed though" - personally I do it anyway, since deciding whether it's needed or not tends not to be an exact science. Anyway doing it makes the code simpler, no need for a destructor.

Comment: Out of memory isn't the only issue. Any exception in the constructor of later members will cause the same issues. And note that even if today none of the members throw, you probably don't want to manually review your whole code base if you add an exception to a type later in time. It is much easier to just solve the non issue now than expect an fragile solution to work.

Comment: @Steve, life would be prettier if everyone did that (and myself, I do not use raw pointer allocation anyway), but I just pointed out that for most people it's a non-issue.

Comment: @David, true, but not in this particular case. I'll edit the answer though.

Comment: @Kornel: fair enough, I'm just saying that I faintly disapprove of "most people" ;-)

Comment: @Steve, when was the last time you've seen try-catch protected new statements in code other than yours? :>

Comment: @Kornel: well, try-catch protected new statements are only step 1, where step 0 is "ignore exceptions entirely". Step 2 is to make all your code offer exception guarantees *in general*, and then any exceptions due to out of memory will be dealt with naturally as a side-effect of that. As you've said, if we were allocating a user-defined type instead of `int`, then we'd have to be aware of the risk of an exception from its constructor, we couldn't say "ah well, if we run out of memory we're hosed anyway so there's no point bothering". So we might as well just do it always.

Answer (score 3):

There's no specific issue with calling `new` from the initializer list.

However, if you do it for multiple members, it won't be exception-safe, and you risk leaking memory (what if the first `new` call succeeds, but the second throws an exception? Then the first allocation is leaked).

As for relying on the initialization order, that's perfectly safe. Members are initialized in the order in which they're listed in the class declaration. So you can use the value of members initialized early, to initialize "later" members.

Just keep in mind that it's their declaration order inside the class, and *not* their order in the initialization list that determines their initialization order. :)

Comment: So am I right is saying that this would work, even though it looks odd and I believe many standards say you should do them in the order as in the class? `Test(void) : k(new int[count]), count(10)`

Comment: @Firedragon: Yes, as long as `count` and `k` stay in the correct order relative to each other in the class definition.

Comment: @Firedragon: yes, that would still work. GCC would warn for it, though, since it's confusing to read.

Comment: Yeah, it would work. But you should only do it if you're actively trying to confuse the reader ;)

Answer (score 3):

You are allocating memory in your initialiser-list; this is totally fine, but you are then assigning the pointers to that memory to raw pointers.

These raw pointers do not imply any sort of memory ownership or deletion of the pointers that they point to, and as a result, the code contains several memory leaks, does not follow the "Rule of Five", and is generally bad.

A far better way to write `Test` would be:

```
class Test
{
private:
    //Assuming you actually want dynamic memory allocation:
    std::unique_ptr<int> i;
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> j;
    int count;
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> k;

public:
    Test(void) : i(new int), j(new int[10]), count(10), k(new int[count])
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you have:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    T* p1;
    T* p2;

    Foo()
    : p1(new T),
      p2(new T)
    {
    }
};
```

If initializing `p2` fails (either because `new` throws an out of memory exception or because the `T` constructor fails), then `p1` will be leaked.  To combat this, C++ allows using `try`/`catch` in initialization lists, but it's usually pretty gross.

Answer (score 1):

Steve Jessop's answer presents pitfalls.

About the order, which I think is what your question addressed:

> 12.6.2/4
>
> Initialization shall proceed in the following order:
>
> [...]
>
> - Then, nonstatic data members shall be initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order
>     of the mem-initializers).

Since in your class, `count` is declared before `k`, you're ok.