# How to fix this memory leak in C++ project?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have very simple code snippet:

```
struct simple_string
{
    simple_string(size_t size, char ch)
    : buffer_(new Buffer(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>>(size, ch).c_str(), size)) //first memory leak
    {
    }

    ~simple_string()
    {
        buffer_->release();
        delete buffer_;
    }

    struct Buffer
    {
        explicit Buffer(const char* str, size_t size)
        : str_(new char[size + 1]), //second memory leak
        count_(1)
        {
            std::char_traits<char>::copy(str_, str, size + 1);
        }

        void release()
        {
            if (this != nullptr)
            {
                --count_;

                if (count_ == 0)
                {
                    delete[] str_;
                }
            }
        }

        void acquire()
        {
            ++count_;
        }

        char* str_;
        size_t count_;
    } *buffer_;
};

int main() {
    simple_string a(3, 'a');

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand, why memory leaks exist. Both raw pointers deleted in end of program life. Maybe I should not have to create pointers in initializer lists of constructors?

Comment: _"Maybe I should not have to create pointers in initializer lists of constructors?"_ That's usually not a problem. How are your memory leaks detected exactly?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I use Valgrind and built-in memory leak checker in Visual Studio. Both tools say, that there are memory leaks.

Comment: I can't see an unconditional `delete [] str_;`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, there is no unconditional `delete [] str_;`. But, It seems, that in my case, there is a call of `delete [] str_;`.

Comment: Did you actually check that with the debugger? _"It seems"_ is too vague for my taste.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, of course, I did. `delete [] str_;` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get memory leak using g++ 4.8.2 + valgrind 3.10.

I get it however in VS 2015 EE detecting with CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC but that is a false positive.

Set `str_` and `buffer_` to nullptr after deleting pointers and then call destructor explicitly: `a.~simple_string();`, it will call destructor twice nothing really doing for the second time but it will show no memory leak because the first time the destructor was called before outputting the memory leaks results.

**EDIT:** This false positive memory leak can be work arounded (in VS2015 EE at least) by creating `simple_string` object in a function instead of in `main()`:

```
void foo()
{
    simple_string a(3, 'a');
}

int main() 
{
    foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it works, but I don't understand, why I should to call destructor explicitly.

Comment: @David No, you don't need to call destructor explicitly, it was just to prove that the memory leak detector is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

[Are there any issues with allocating memory within constructor initialization lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064298/are-there-any-issues-with-allocating-memory-within-constructor-initialization-li)

Try switching to real smart pointers, maybe the memory leaks you are getting are warnings instead of actual leaks at that moment?

Comment: I get `class Test` from that example. Memory leaks exist too.

Comment: Did you read the answer and comments?, it is not a solution for you problem on that example, it does have memory leaks, the answer is your solution, switching to smart pointers.